# Parse an entire JSON object looking for a key in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to find if a certain key is in a json object.  I create the json with

```
googleRequest = json.loads(googleRequest.content) # its a google api call
```

The json is not always formatted the same way, and I want to find if a certain key is somewhere in the json.  I have tried using this:

```
if "----" is in jsonObject:
    do stuff
```

However this only works if the key is in the first level of the json.  Is there a way to parse through a json object looking for a certain key, no matter where the key is located?

Here is an incomplete mock up of the json:

```
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 1,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "HDvHjwEACAAJ",
   "etag": "+2K7d2N2VNg",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/HDvHjwEACAAJ",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Fahrenheit 451",
    "authors": [
     "Ray Bradbury"
    ],
    "publisher": "Voyager",
    "publishedDate": "2013",
    "description": "The terrifyingly prophetic novel of a post-literate future Guy Montag is a fireman. His job is to destroy the most illegal of commodities, the source of all discord and unhappiness, the printed book.",
```

and I want to be able to find the title, even if its under "kind" or "volumeInfo" and save its value.

EDIT:

I have this function:

```
def find_key(dic, key_match):
  keys=[]
  values=[]
  if isinstance(dic,dict):
    for key,value in dic.items():
      if isinstance(value,dict):
        keys.append(key)
        keys.append(find_key(value, key_match))
      elif isinstance(value,list):
        keys.append(key)
        keys.append(find_key(value[0], key_match))
      else:
        keys.append(key)
        if key == key_match:
          print value #PRINTS OUT WHAT I WANT
          values.append(value)
   return values # in line with for loop
```

the print out statement i signaled prints what i want, but i cant get the function to return that value.  It just returns empty [].

Comment: `values` is empty at the end of the function cause `value` is a local of a for loop, it is overiden at each loop, you can use the module copy, and make `values.append(deepcopy(value))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested function with looping over your `dictionary` items and check the type of values each time , if the type was `list` or `dict` you call the function again else you append the key to list of your total keys  :

```
def find_key(dic):
 keys=[]
 if isinstance(dic,dict): 
  for key,value in dic.items():
     if isinstance(value,dict):
        keys.append(key)
        keys.append(find_key(value))
     elif isinstance(value,list):
         keys.append(key)
         keys.append(find_key(value[0]))
     else:
        keys.append(key)
  return keys
```

result :

```
['totalItems', 'items', ['kind', 'etag', 'volumeInfo', ['publisher', 'publishedDate', 'authors', None, 'description', 'title'], 'id', 'selfLink'], 'kind']
```

Comment: so if im looking for "title", where would i put it?  is it value?

Comment: @user2455869 i edit the answer and add the `keys.append(key)` to inner if loops and result please try that !

Comment: I see what you did, but i do no want the objects in the json.  Just a list of all the keys.

Comment: I am using your function and put an edit in my original question

Comment: @user2455869 ... im glad !that it was helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Build a function that iterates over the JSON object, recursively:

- If the key is in the current level, return its value.
- If not, run the function for all inner dictionaries.

Comment: how would i do the second part of that?

Comment: You could check if the value of the current key is either a list or a dict. If it's a dict, call your function recursively. If it's a list, call it for every compound (list or dict) object in it.

Answer (score 0):

for python 3

```
# python 3 only
def find_values_from_key(key, json_object):
    if isinstance(json_object, list):
        for list_element in json_object:
            yield from find_values_from_key(key, list_element)
    elif isinstance(json_object, dict):
        if key in json_object:
            yield json_object[key]
        for dict_value in json_object.values():
            yield from find_values_from_key(key, dict_value)
```

for python 2

```
# python 2 only
def find_values_from_key(key, json_object):
    if isinstance(json_object, list):
        for list_element in json_object:
            for res in find_values_from_key(key, list_element):
                yield res
    elif isinstance(json_object, dict):
        if key in json_object:
            yield json_object[key]
        for dict_value in json_object.values():
            for res in find_values_from_key(key, dict_value):
                yield res
```

Comment: it is of course -_- but the form `yield from` is new, just learnt it

Comment: For your edit, i got <generator object find_values_from_key at 0x10c5797d0>

Comment: it's an iterator so you need to do something with it like `for x in find_values_from_key('my_key', json_object): # do something with x` or `list(find_values_from_key('my_key', json_object)` if you want a list, same with tuple etc

Answer (score 0):

```
"title":\s*"([^"]+)"
```

Try using `re` is other things dont work.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/3

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'"title":\s*"([^"]+)"')
test_str = u"{\n \"kind\": \"books#volumes\",\n \"totalItems\": 1,\n \"items\": [\n {\n \"kind\": \"books#volume\",\n \"id\": \"HDvHjwEACAAJ\",\n \"etag\": \"+2K7d2N2VNg\",\n \"selfLink\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/HDvHjwEACAAJ\",\n \"volumeInfo\": {\n \"title\": \"Fahrenheit 451\",\n \"authors\": [\n \"Ray Bradbury\"\n ],\n \"publisher\": \"Voyager\",\n \"publishedDate\": \"2013\",\n \"description\": \"The terrifyingly prophetic novel of a post-literate future Guy Montag is a fireman. His job is to destroy the most illegal of commodities, the source of all discord and unhappiness, the printed book.\",\n\n\n\n\n\n <div style=\"padding-left:2em;\">\n &bull; Location: \n\n Northern Virginia, â˜Ž 202-210-5936\n\n </div>\n\n\n\n\n <div style=\"padding-left:2em;\"><br />&bull; Post ID: 1234567 washingtondc</div>\n\n\n <div id=\"OtherAdsByThisUser\" data-oid=\"7654321\">"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```