# How to select columns of data from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, limesurvey

**I'm retrieving survey results from Lime Survey via its API (Remote Control):**

[image]

**And I manage to get it into a DataFrame. But it's just 1 column per row:**

[image]

**The data looks like this.**

[image]

What I want to be able to do is get averages of the data by question and category. From the example below, q10[wor1], q10[wor2], . . ., q10[wor7] give the 7 questions that are part of category q10.

How to first select all the data for wor1, wor2, ..., wor7, separately, so that I can do stats on each of those individual questions.

Then how do I select all data for q10* so that I can do stats for the entire group?

Even without trying to separate the category from the question, I haven't been able to select just all the 'q10[wor1]' data.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead provide a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I realized that I can request CSV instead JSON from Lime Survey. Made things much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jq - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

You can pass your df ['responses'] json to jq and extract the required field and create that as a separate df column.

And then you can get the average of the columns from the df.

Comment: This looks like a possible solution. But I'd prefer a pure python solution.

Comment: You could use the same using the in-built json library in Python too. Since, your data is wrapped inside an index, you might have to iterate through all keys to extract the required fields. See here for ref -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954716/parse-an-entire-json-object-looking-for-a-key-in-python

jQ library will help you cut down on the extra lines of code and will be straight forward.